# Python meta class - verifying the name of class where instance of other class with meta was initialized

Tags: python, metaclass

I'm not sure if it is possible. I need to verify (with `meta`), the name of class which initializes the instance of class enhanced with `meta` in order to allow (or not) to use its class methods. I have prepared pseudo code to show what I need.

```
class meta:
    __call__(cls, name, base, dict)
    if some_class_name != "b":
        del dict("some_func")


class a:
    def some_func():
        code code

class b:
    a_instance = a()
    a_instance.some_func()
```

`a.some_func()` can be only used when the class name's where it was called  is b. Otherwise this method should be deleted from object.

Comment: You want to check the name in a class inheriting from `a`, or in a class having an instance of `a` in a class attribute, as in your code? Or should the instance of `a` be in an attribute of instances of `b`?

Answer (score 0):

This could be made with a metaclass, but it would not be needed, and might be a bit less effective

Normally people worry about metaclasses to modify a class as it is created, and then customize the `__new__` or `__init__` methods. By customizing the metaclass `__getattribute__` you could, yes, control which methods are visible in each instance of the class - but that can also be made directly from your base class  `__getattribute__`. At class creation time, we need to annotate the guarded methods and that can be done with the `__init_subclass__` class method.

Now, to check the class name where one instance is bould as an attribute, that is more complicated: when code is run, it won't "know" where it was called from -
One could do `a().some_func()` at top level code: that creates an instance of "a", and runs the method without the instance ever being bound to any local or global variable.

Python do allow introspection of running code, so the called code (either the code in `some_func` or code in `a.__getattribute__` can "see" the local variables where that code was called. Since the caller could "forge" local variables to whatever they'd like, this alone would not restrict code to be run - but it could be used as a simple mechanism to avoid someone that would unknowingly call the functions from "wrong places" at runtime.

Note that this code aditionally requieres that the calling method has a local `self` variable that points to the instance - and that is used to check the class name (as I said, this is easy to circunvent, but will avoid people calling your methods by mistake)
The restriction should be documented - and be cunted upon just as a safeguard.
So instead of a metaclass, there is a "RestrictorBase" class that should be inherited from any classes that have the protected methods. And them, for each method you want to protect by name in this way, you should apply the  `allowed_from` decorator as bellow. As the comparison is with the `in` operator,
it will automatically work with single strings or with tuples of strings (say, you want it to work from "a" and "b").

```py
import inspect

RestrictedRegistry = {}


class RestrictorBase:
    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        for attrname, attr in cls.__dict__.items():
            if allowed:=getattr(attr, "_allowed_from", None):
                RestrictedRegistry[attr] = allowed
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
            
            
    def __getattribute__(self, attrname):
        attr = super().__getattribute__(attrname)
        if (func:=getattr(attr, "__func__", None)) and func in RestrictedRegistry:
            caller_vars = inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_locals
            if "self" in caller_vars and caller_vars["self"].__class__.__name__ in RestrictedRegistry[func]:
                return attr
            raise AttributeError(f" {self.__class__.__name__!r} object has no attribute {attrname}")
            
        return attr

    
def allowed_from(names):
    def deco(func):
        func._allowed_from = names
        return func
    return deco

def hashable(obj):
    try:
        hash(obj)
    except TypeError:
        return False
    return True


class a(RestrictorBase):
    @allowed_from('b')
    def some_func(self):
        print("Restricted function running")

class b:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a_instance = a()
        
    def other_method(self):
        self.a_instance.some_func()
```

And this is the code above running in the interactive interpreter:

```py
In [121]: b().other_method()                                                                                        
Restricted function running

In [122]: class c(b): pass                                                                                          

In [123]: c().other_method()                                                                                        
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-123-6746b8f5138c> in <module>
----> 1 c().other_method()
[...]
AttributeError:  'a' object has no attribute some_func

In [124]:
```